# Submit MVC ListBoxFor values to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a multiselect ListBoxFor control as shown in mvc view

```
@using ExampleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveExample", "Example", FormMethod.Post, new { @id 
= "exampleForm" }))
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.AssignedContainers, new 
    MultiSelectList(Model.RegisteredContainers, "ID", "Description", null), 
    new { @class = "fieldNoFocusRequiredListBox", @size = 15, 
    id="RegisteredContainers" }) 
}
```

View model code looks like this:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public int[] AssignedContainers { get; set; }
    public List<Container_Sizes> RegisteredContainers { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult SaveExample(ExampleViewModel model)
{
    // code
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I was able to bind the listbox with model property RegisteredContainers. I do some some jQuery validation and then submit the form via ajax like this:

```
function SaveProduct() {

if (!ValidateProductForm()) {       
    return;
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#exampleForm').serialize(),
    url: '/Example/SaveExample/',
    success: function (result) {  
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, error, errorThrown) {            
    }
});
```

}

When the break point hits the controller ExampleViewModel -> AssignedContainers is null. Please note that i used ICollection/IEnumerable/List for this property AssignedContainers but no luck. Also when i see $('#exampleForm').serialize() in debugger watch i see ".....&AssignedContainers=17" as there is one item in the list box but received null on controller.

Do i need any updates to model binder or what is going wrong here?

Comment: Your code as shown works fine and the `AssignedContainers` will be bound. If its not working for you, its due to something you have not told us

Comment: I removed all the other code and made it look exactly like above, still not working(AssignedContainers =null). Did you try this code?

Comment: Are you looking for complete code? PS: ViewModel and .cshtml view code are many lines.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Basically, i have a listbox (AvailableContainers) that is populated from the db table data on a product record. Then user picks from this list box (AvailableContainers) to another list box (AssignedContainers ) on button click through jQuery. Later, on save click i need to save the values from AssignedContainers  to db. I have problem displaying the empty list box too. If the product record exists, then it will have some assignedContainers if not, empty control should be rendered to save the product record with assignedcontainers . Please help. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in your question about a 2nd list box and moving options from one to another (the code you have shown works fine so its the code you have not shown which is your issue and we cannot guess what that is)